# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "_pkey"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, one-to-many

I get this error when I try to update two entity with relanshionship one-to-many.

This is first entity class:

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SelectBeforeUpdate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tags", schema = "public")
@NoArgsConstructor
@SelectBeforeUpdate
@Data
public class Tag {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "tag")
  private String tag;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
  private Product product;

  public Tag(String tag, Product product) {
    this.tag = tag;
    this.product = product;
  }
}
```

This is second entity class:

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import com.example.demo.dto.ProductDto;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "products", schema = "public")
@Data
public class Product {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "price")
  private double price;

  @Column(name = "added")
  private Date added;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
  private List<Tag> tags;

  public Product(final ProductDto productDto) {
    this.id = productDto.getId();
    this.name = productDto.getName();
    this.price = productDto.getPrice();
    this.added = new Date(productDto.getAdded());
    this.tags = convertTagDtoToTag(productDto.getTags());
  }

  public List<Tag> convertTagDtoToTag(final List<String> tagDtos) {
    return tagDtos
        .stream()
        .map(t -> new Tag(t, this))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

This method where I try to update:

```
  public Product updateProduct(final ProductDto productDto) {
    final Product product = this.productRepository.findById(productDto.getId()).map(p -> {
      p.setName(productDto.getName());
      p.setPrice(productDto.getPrice());
      p.setAdded(new Date(productDto.getAdded()));
      p.getTags().clear();
      p.getTags().addAll(p.convertTagDtoToTag(productDto.getTags()));

      return p;
    }).orElse(null);

    return this.productRepository.save(product);
  }
```

And i get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tags_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

I write this method, but i think there is better way.

```
  public Product updateProduct(final ProductDto productDto) {
    final Product product = this.productRepository.findById(productDto.getId()).map(p -> {
      p.setName(productDto.getName());
      p.setPrice(productDto.getPrice());
      p.setAdded(new Date(productDto.getAdded()));
      updateTag(p.getTags(), p.convertTagDtoToTag(productDto.getTags()));

      return p;
    }).orElse(null);

    return this.productRepository.save(product);
  }

  private void updateTag(List<Tag> serverTags, List<Tag> frontedTags) {
    for (int i = 0; i < serverTags.size(); i++) {
      serverTags.get(i).setTag(frontedTags.get(i).getTag());
    }
  }
```

Also I have data.sql file

```
INSERT INTO products (id, name, price, added) values (1, 'First product', 100, '2000-09-01');

INSERT INTO products (id, name, price, added)
values (2, 'Second product', 200, '2010-10-11');

INSERT INTO products (id, name, price, added)
values (3, 'Third product', 300, '2010-11-04');

INSERT INTO tags (id, tag, product_id)
values (1, 'tag1', 1);

INSERT INTO tags (id, tag, product_id)
values (2, 'tag2', 1);

INSERT INTO tags (id, tag, product_id)
values (3, 'tag3', 1);

INSERT INTO tags (id, tag, product_id)
values (4, 'tag4', 2);

INSERT INTO tags (id, tag, product_id)
values (5, 'tag5', 3);
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: First thing I see you should't clear your entity tags. Just loop it and update with incoming data (but do not touch ids). If you want to add new tags - simply create new and add them to existing tags. Second thing is it can be id generation strategy issue. Hibernate probably doesn't see existed id (1), and tries to start its own sequence from the beginning which is 1 too... It happens sometimes, especially if you fill tables with sample data manually or by tools like liquibase.

Comment: I have data.sql file

Answer (score 0):

Please try to insert by getting the value of the next ID that way:

```
INSERT INTO products (id, name, price, added)
values (
       SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('products', 'id'), coalesce(max(id)+1, 1), false) FROM products, 
       'Second product', 
       200, 
       '2010-10-11'
       );
```